# java mail: IMAP, renaming a folder which has children

Tags: email, directory, jakarta-mail, imap, rename

I use latest java mail api. I want to rename an IMAP folder which contains children (subfolders). Suppose we have inbox and inbox has one subfolder **inbox.folder1**. 
The folder1 has one subfolder its full name is **inbox.folder1.subfolder1**

I want to rename folder1 to folder2 and i want that to see:

**inbox.folder2.subfolder1**

but after the code

```
// folder instance corresponds to folder1
newFolder = folder.getFolder(newName); //newName = "folder2"
folder.renameTo(newFolder);
```

i have if you connect using outlook or thunderbird

**inbox.folder1.subfolder1**

**inbox.folder2**

we have two folders, but i expect one. And also subfolder1 still sitting in folder1. And you can not enter folder or subfolder1, they generate error message: *Reason Given: Mailbox does not exist, or must be subscribed to.*

Should i use setSubscripbed(true/false)? Do I have to handle subfolders separately by iterating each one?

Comment: This is server specific: but normally when you rename a folder, all it's subfolders should be parented/renamed with it.  When that happens, you really need to flush or fix any cache of folder names you have.  In Thunderbird, that usually means restarting it.   In personal experience, Yahoo has implementation problems with this.

Comment: when i connect to mailserver with outlook and thunderbird, the rename operation executes correctly. only when i try to rename with java  side, problems occur. As i understood, i have to take care for the subfolders and/or add some check steps, only folder.renameTo(folder) will not be enough?

Comment: And when i try to rename a folder which does not have subfolders, the process completes fine without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I solved. First i turned on debugging mode of thunderbird as stated in:

https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailNews:Logging#Environment_Variables_to_set

Then i renamed a folder which contained many subfolders.

As you see, you have to call subscribe to folders with new name and unscribe with old name with the order specified in the log file.

Without calling the subscribe/unsubscribe method calls, you get the message in the mail server console

**68 OK Folder renamed.**

but it is not enough and you have corrupted folder structure.

*9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:SendData: 68 rename "INBOX.folder1" "INBOX.folder2"
9944[ab79a70]: ReadNextLine [stream=a6db068 nb=23 needmore=0]
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 68 OK Folder renamed.
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:SendData: 69 subscribe "INBOX.folder2"
9944[ab79a70]: ReadNextLine [stream=a6db068 nb=26 needmore=0]
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 69 OK Folder subscribed.
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:SendData: 70 unsubscribe "INBOX.folder1"
9944[ab79a70]: ReadNextLine [stream=a6db068 nb=28 needmore=0]
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 70 OK Folder unsubscribed.
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:SendData: 71 subscribe "INBOX.folder2.subfolder1.subsubfolder1.subsubsubfolder1b"
9944[ab79a70]: ReadNextLine [stream=a6db068 nb=26 needmore=0]
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 71 OK Folder subscribed.
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:SendData: 72 unsubscribe "INBOX.folder1.subfolder1.subsubfolder1.subsubsubfolder1b"
9944[ab79a70]: ReadNextLine [stream=a6db068 nb=28 needmore=0]
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 72 OK Folder unsubscribed.
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:SendData: 73 subscribe "INBOX.folder2.subfolder1.subsubfolder1.subsubsubfolder1a"
9944[ab79a70]: ReadNextLine [stream=a6db068 nb=26 needmore=0]
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 73 OK Folder subscribed.
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:SendData: 74 unsubscribe "INBOX.folder1.subfolder1.subsubfolder1.subsubsubfolder1a"
9944[ab79a70]: ReadNextLine [stream=a6db068 nb=28 needmore=0]
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 74 OK Folder unsubscribed.
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:SendData: 75 subscribe "INBOX.folder2.subfolder3.subsubfolder3"
9944[ab79a70]: ReadNextLine [stream=a6db068 nb=26 needmore=0]
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 75 OK Folder subscribed.
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:SendData: 76 unsubscribe "INBOX.folder1.subfolder3.subsubfolder3"
9944[ab79a70]: ReadNextLine [stream=a6db068 nb=28 needmore=0]
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 76 OK Folder unsubscribed.
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:SendData: 77 subscribe "INBOX.folder2.subfolder3"
9944[ab79a70]: ReadNextLine [stream=a6db068 nb=26 needmore=0]
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 77 OK Folder subscribed.
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:SendData: 78 unsubscribe "INBOX.folder1.subfolder3"
9944[ab79a70]: ReadNextLine [stream=a6db068 nb=28 needmore=0]
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 78 OK Folder unsubscribed.
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:SendData: 79 subscribe "INBOX.folder2.subfolder1.subsubfolder1"
9944[ab79a70]: ReadNextLine [stream=a6db068 nb=26 needmore=0]
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 79 OK Folder subscribed.
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:SendData: 80 unsubscribe "INBOX.folder1.subfolder1.subsubfolder1"
9944[ab79a70]: ReadNextLine [stream=a6db068 nb=28 needmore=0]
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 80 OK Folder unsubscribed.
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:SendData: 81 subscribe "INBOX.folder2.subfolder2"
9944[ab79a70]: ReadNextLine [stream=a6db068 nb=26 needmore=0]
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 81 OK Folder subscribed.
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:SendData: 82 unsubscribe "INBOX.folder1.subfolder2"
9944[ab79a70]: ReadNextLine [stream=a6db068 nb=28 needmore=0]
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 82 OK Folder unsubscribed.
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:SendData: 83 subscribe "INBOX.folder2.subfolder1"
9944[ab79a70]: ReadNextLine [stream=a6db068 nb=26 needmore=0]
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 83 OK Folder subscribed.
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:SendData: 84 unsubscribe "INBOX.folder1.subfolder1"
9944[ab79a70]: ReadNextLine [stream=a6db068 nb=28 needmore=0]
9944[ab79a70]: 7cea000:192.168.0.104:A:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 84 OK Folder unsubscribed.*